Pandas pivot/melt 'loses' index
Say I have the following table, BP_narrow:
    subject when    sbp
0   BHO before  160
1   GWB before  115
2   WJC after   145
3   GWB after   135
4   WJC before  105

I perform a pivot (narrow to wide):
pivoted = pd.pivot(BP_narrow, index = "subject", columns = "when", values = "sbp")
pivoted.head()

when    after   before
subject     
BHO 160 160
GWB 135 115
WJC 145 105

When I try to 'melt' it back to its original form, I get an error. I'm trying to use:
pivotedBack = pivoted.melt()
pivotedBack.head()

    when    value
0   after   160
1   after   135
2   after   145
3   before  160
4   before  115

I expected a dataframe that looked roughly like this when I was done (pivotedBack):
        index   when    value
0   BHO before  160
1   GWB before  115
2   WJC after   145
3   GWB after   135
4   WJC before  105

I've lost 'subject'! I assume it has to do with the hierarchical column indexes, but I can't figure out how to flatten them to get the data back into its original form. Doing reset_index() along the way doesn't help.
Any ideas?

you can use pivotedBack = pivoted.melt(ignore_index=False)
